# WebFlux does not return given status

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-restcontroller

I am using WebFlux with RestControllers. My method returns `Mono<ResponseEntity<User>>` object.
I am mapping Mono into ResponseEntity like this.

```
userService.flatMap(authenticationService::signUp)
    .map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED));
```

But it returns only 200 status code. No matter what status code I set.
How can I return other status codes like 201,204,... etc?

Comment: Show the rest of the controller

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mono<ResponseEntity>` as the return type of method to get the set status.